# Camera app does not return to my activity

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to launch the camera app to get a photo but when I press the ok button, the camera app is still in foreground, and my activity cannot resume.

Here is what I do:

```
    File file = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.problem_creating_file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    takePhotoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I've found lots of solutions on Internet but no one worked for me :(

Comment: can you post your onActivityResult() code?

Comment: The onActivityResult() is never called because the app is never resumed.

Comment: @DanieleVitali : which launch mode you have selected for Activity from which you are calling startActivityForResult?

Comment: didn't you write the onActivityResult() method in your class???

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  Sorry, what you mean with "launch mode"?

Comment: Press the BACK button after pressing OK to accept the picture, and see what happens.

Comment: @HamidShatu Please read carefully. I've written that onActivityResult() is never called. I didn't say that I have not written the onActivityResult() method. If you want I can show you, but I think it is useless to resolve this issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nothing change. The camera app stays in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching a third-party activity. There is nobody forcing the authors of that activity to do anything that you seek, including:

- taking a picture
- storing the picture at your requested location
- immediately returning to your app once the picture is taken

*Many* camera apps will do at least the first two of those things. One hopes that all camera apps would take a picture, but there's probably at least one out there with bugs in its `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementation.

Hence, you and your app must not make any assumptions about what the third-party app is doing when you ask it to take a picture. In particular, you need to be aware that the user may need to press BACK to leave the camera app and return to yours, depending upon the implementation of the user's chosen camera app. And it is entirely possible that a buggy camera app will not even honor the BACK button, in which case the user needs to choose a better camera app.

Comment: Sounds like "never use default camera app" :)
However, I'm using two devices to test. One of them is the Nexus 5. Do you think even the Nexus 5 can have a buggy camera app?

Comment: @DanieleVitali: "Sounds like "never use default camera app" " -- you are not using the default camera app. You are using whatever camera app the user chooses to use. If the user has not installed a third-party camera app that offers `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, then you will be using the device's pre-installed camera app. But there are plenty of third-party apps, and plenty of users who use them.

Comment: @DanieleVitali: "Do you think even the Nexus 5 can have a buggy camera app?" -- from the standpoint of the authors, it may not be buggy, it just may not be behaving in a manner that you expect. Again, there's very little documented about what's even *supposed* to happen for things like this, let alone any sort of enforcement. This is one of the reasons why I am writing the CWAC-Camera library, to allow for lightweight camera work in an app without depending on a third party app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I'll take a look to your library ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this...

```
takePhotoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a picture taken and none of the strange effects a camera has you can write a camera class to use in your app so you have control of its functionality.